# Cypher query can't find node by label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using the neo4j browser to search for a node in my graph by label. I know the node exists and the label on the node is correct, but when I specify the label on the node, neo4j can't find it.

More specifically, I use the following cypher query in the neo4j browser:

```
match (a:Foo) where a.value = "Bar" return a
(no changes, no records)
```

However a node with that value does exist with that label:

```
match (a) where a.value = "Bar" return labels(a)
["Foo"]
```

There is an index on that label, but I don't know if that is relevant.

```
:schema
Indexes
   ON :Foo(value) ONLINE
```

Additionally, explicitly resetting the label doesn't seem to work:

```
match (a) where a.value = "Bar" 
set a :Foo
return a
```

Will return the node with the correct label applied, but when I retry my original query it still cannot find the node.

This has worked previously, but I have made some changes recently to our heap size/ page cache size /gc type trying to run down another issue with 100% cpu hangs on garbage collection. None of those changes should have affected labels.

Has anyone had this experience before?

I'm using Neo4j CE v3.3.0

Comment: Does doing a `REMOVE a:Foo` before the `SET` help? If not, and this is a problem with just a single node, you could try replacing that node with a new one (and re-creating all its relationships as well).

Comment: @cybersam Adding the `REMOVE` still "worked" in that it didn't throw an error or anything, but I still can't find that node by label.

Comment: It may be worth dropping the index then creating it again. I have a feeling somehow your index is corrupted

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I dropped and recreated it and that seemed to solve the problem. Any idea what could have caused it? Or a way to detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue of index corruption, as mentioned in my comment, dropping then creating the index again should fix it.

As to how the index got corrupted, I can't say, but you are using a .0 release, and those tend to have more bugs than others. You may want to upgrade to the latest 3.3.x release.

You can always run the consistency check via neo4j-admin to see if anything else might be going on with your graph data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ran the consistency check, and found several but I have no clue what these mean or how to fix it, and couldn't find anything in the manual. Any thoughts? WARN : The schema rule contained in the DynamicRecord chain has a reference to a schema rule that is not online.
        DynamicRecord[11,used=true,(53),type=-1,data=byte[size=53],start=true,next=-1]
        Inconsistent with: IndexRule[id=11, descriptor=Index( GENERAL, :label[106](property[1]) ), provider={key=lucene+native, version=1.0}]

Comment: You can try to drop and recreate all your indexes and constraints, see if that will allow the consistency check to pass

Answer (score 0):

This did not work

```
MATCH ( p:item {name:"spam"}) RETURN p.name
```

(no changes, no records)

But this did work:

```
Match (n:item) Where n.name =~ '.*spam.*' Return n.name, n.purchase

n.name  n.purchase

"""spam"""  8
```